Detecting recurring images in a video file using DVT
I am trying to figure out how to use the Distant Viewing Toolkit, a Python package, to analyze a video file. Specifically, I want to see if specific images are repeated more than others.
I am using the Jupyter Notebook for this project. The version of Python I'm using is 3.9.12.
Presently, these are the lines of code I have written.
import dvt
from dvt import load_video
import os
desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop")
video_file_name = "Video_File.mp4"
video_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, video_file_name)
video = load_video(video_path, height=720, width=1280)

These lines of code appear to have functioned just fine. However, I am uncertain where to go from here.
I have tried the following line of code: dvt.AnnoDetect(video) However, it's not producing the results I'm looking for. I've tried numerous other variations of code, but none have worked.
I know that I'm probably oversimplifying this a lot, but I'm still fairly new to Python. If you can offer some guidance, I would be very grateful.
